# SQL update query throwing a syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

**Problem**

I am trying to create a database management system in the form of a form application. I am using a Microsoft Access database. I have one particular SQL update query which is throwing an error and I cannot work out what is the cause of the error and would like to ask for help with how to make it work. I am confused since I have used update queries a number of times with no problem. I have already tried to look at whether this is due to the query using any oledb reserved words and I couldn't find any being used. I have checked that all the quotation markings are correctly used according to the data types of the data I have put in the query. I have also checked that table field names are correct.

The line...

```
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

...is the one where the error is thrown.

**Code**

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
command2.Connection = connection;
query = "update Clients set FirstName='" + txt_FirstName.Text + "', Surname='" + txt_Surname.Text + "', AddressFirstLine='" + txt_AddressFirstLine.Text + "', AddressSecondLine='" + txt_AddressSecondLine.Text + "', AddressTown='" + txt_AddressTown.Text + "', AddressPostcode='" + txt_AddressPostcode.Text + "', Email='" + txt_Email.Text + "', Telephone='" + txt_TelephoneNumber.Text + "', Username='" + txt_Username.Text + "', UKARAID='" + txt_UKARAID.Text + "', where ClientID=" + txt_ClientID.Text;
MessageBox.Show(query);
command2.CommandText = query;
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

**Error Dialog**

[image: Error Dialog]

Thanks in advance for your help! If there's anything else I can provide that might help answer my question let me know.

PS. I am aware of parametrized queries and WILL be implementing them so don't worry about that. :)

Comment: Extra comma before `WHERE`.

Comment: Well, that should give you some clue about why to use parameterized queries. Not only useful to prevent SQL injection, but also makes it far easier to spot the errors in your SQL statement string.

Comment: Thankyou @Amadan for your answer. That's exactly what the problem was! Hard to believe I could not find this myself.

Comment: No worries. Simple typo, happens to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a comma before the where, you need to remove that ( "', where ClientID=")

```
query = "update Clients set FirstName='" + txt_FirstName.Text + "', Surname='" + txt_Surname.Text + "', AddressFirstLine='" + txt_AddressFirstLine.Text + "', AddressSecondLine='" + txt_AddressSecondLine.Text + "', AddressTown='" + txt_AddressTown.Text + "', AddressPostcode='" + txt_AddressPostcode.Text + "', Email='" + txt_Email.Text + "', Telephone='" + txt_TelephoneNumber.Text + "', Username='" + txt_Username.Text + "', UKARAID='" + txt_UKARAID.Text + "' where ClientID=" + txt_ClientID.Text;
```

Comment: Yes thank you, Amadan had the answer.